# What are Unity's problems with garbage collection

Tags: unity

I've been asked this in interviews before and I can never seem to find a definite answer. I know Unity's garbage collection isn't great, but if you were to ask this question in an interview, what would you expect to hear?

Comment: I would recommend to prepare for the next interview by reading [the manual section about garbage collection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/performance-garbage-collector.html).

Comment: While this question *is* subjective as different dev's can have varying opinions about why Unity's GC isn't (or is) great, I think it meets the criteria for good subjective. Answers that explain why / how the GC is problematic, share experiences or are backed up with facts and references *should* be the sort of thing that a game dev interview is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what answer is expected but if I'm asked on an interview I would say the "problem" is that GC requires freezing of the state of the program but games are usually very dynamic. This makes those freezes much easier to spot with games where there are constant movements on the screen (stuttering).

Until recently GC used by Unity was not incremental, meaning it must do all its job in single game freeze. And that may make those freezes long enough to be noticed.

Now there is an option for incremental GC (i.e. staged GC, freezes more often for shorter times) but it must be profiled if it brings improvement for the current game. Incremental GC have this problem of the state of the game changing between GC stages which can force the GC to re-analyse the changed state over and over from scratch and ultimately be slower than the non-incremental one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for [memory management & garbage collection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-memory.html#garbage):

Allocating managed memory is time-consuming for the CPU, so memory management (including garbage collection) impacts runtime performance. At an extreme, garbage collection can prevent the CPU from doing other work until it completes. Note: I take this to mean "completes some task". As others have noted, the GC is incremental, but while it might not need to stop everything to solve everything (see [prior versions of memory management](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/webgl-memory.html) for details), it may still need to consume CPU time in a way that is noticeable.

Unity's memory management can lead to memory fragmentation, meaning the available & allocated blocks of memory are interspersed. Basically, "gaps" of  available memory form as garbage collection releases memory that's no longer needed. As a result you can have situations where sufficient amount of memory available in the managed heap for some allocation, but it is only available in the "gaps" between allocated objects that are still in use. In that case the managed heap can't find a large enough single block of contiguous memory to perform the assignment. Here's an illustration:

[image: fragmented memory example]

`A` shows the allocation that we want to make
`B` shows available memory: a block from a previously deallocated `string`, a block from a previously deallocated `int[]` & a free block.

If the garbage collector runs & cannot find enough contiguous space, it expands the heaps. Expansion is platform-dependent, so it's not a learn it once apply it everywhere sort of thing - you should consider each separately. The typical expansion is double the amount of the previous expansion.

Eventually Unity releases empty portions of the managed heap back to the operating system, but it doesn't do so at reliable intervals.

Summarizing:

- Memory management & garbage collection require CPU time.
- Garbage collection can lead to fragmentation.
- Fragmentation can lead to not having enough *continuous* memory.
- Lack of continuous memory triggers expansion.
- Expansion rules vary by platform.
- Memory isn't returned back to the OS at predictable intervals.

Answer (score -1):

Garbage collection in Unity refers to the .NET GC.  There is no "problem" with GC other than what you would expect to find with the pros and cons of a GC, and you can read about .NET GC on the web easily.

What they are probably expecting to hear, is that Unity does not do a garbage collection cycle until you call LoadScene and switch to another scene.  LoadAdditive does not call GC.

Comment: Are you sure about the 2nd paragraph? [The documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/performance-garbage-collector.html) says that incremental garbage collection is enabled by default. Are you perhaps working on a project where someone for some reason disabled automatic garbage collection in favor of a custom GC strategy?

Comment: Good point Philipp, I've been working in Unity since like 2008 before they even had c#, and I recalled that's how it worked and was documented.  But re-reading all of the GC docs, It doesn't seem to indicate that at all.